# PHP closure: Extending scope of variable to function

Tags: php, closures

First: I have read all of the possible duplicate posts for this, and I have looked over several sources of documentation and examples, which I have replicated in the below code. However I'm getting syntax errors when writing this in Aptana 3. Is this syntax not legal, or is it perhaps a problem with my environment?

```
class Story {       
    private $storyText;

    function build () use ($storyText)  {
        $storyText .= "blabla";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a syntax error. The `use` statement in this form isn't allowed for a class method. It is for closures only.

I guess you want something like this:

```
class Story {       
    private $storyText;

    public function build ()   {
        $this->storyText .= "blabla";
    };
}
```

Try to start with [PHP's OOP Basics](http://www.php.net/oop5.basic) described in the manual.